# Postfix cannot deliver emails

Tags: email, postfix

I am trying to use postfix as smtp but unfortunately I cannot send any email (unless sending via localhost: ex: webmail).

The error I am getting right now is:

```
Dec 30 16:35:41 h05 postfix/master[3857]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 5903 exit status 1
Dec 30 16:35:41 h05 postfix/master[3857]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
Dec 30 16:35:52 h05 postfix/smtpd[5904]: fatal: parameter "smtpd_recipient_restrictions": specify at least one working instance of: check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination, reject, defer or defer_if_permit
```

while my smtpd_recipient_restriction is configured as follows:

```
cat /etc/postfix/main.cf | grep smtpd_recipient_restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023 permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023 permit_sasl_authenticated
(root@h05)-(~) $ netstat -alpen | grep 10023
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10023         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          5635        2809/postgrey.pid -
```

Anyone has some suggestion? Linux- 2.6.28.9 / Debian 6.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You have two instances of "smtpd_recipient_restrictions"**

surely this is causing the error.

you can edit the file and delete the line that repeated twice.